# Where are pointers stored in?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management

Assuming we have a global variable declared & initialized:

```
short var = 3900;
```

And it is respectively stored in the stack just like that:

```
...[][][][][][][][15][60][][][]... (60 + (15*256) = 3900)
```

Then how/where a new variable pointer will be stored?

```
int p = &var;
```

Is the address stored like a normal integer? Constant? Type-dependent? ( gcc doesn't complain if the pointer is type `char` and the value pointed to is `int`. How come it assigns large number in 1 byte? Optimization?

---

Edit: Oh i get it.
Consider this:

```
int num = 5;
char* p = &num;
```

p is pointer, pointers are more bytes, they can represent such a large address.
Aside this.. *p is char and can't represent larger numbers then 256. 5 is fine.

Comment: yes, an address is stored exactly like an int (on a normal 32 bit system). And yes the address of a variable will be constant throughout the existence of the program.

Comment: It is stored like the other primitive types.

Comment: Is it type-dependant? As i see in C::B along gcc.. it returns no problem if the pointer is type `char` and the value pointed to is `int`

Comment: note : pointer as address is not always possible to hold as an int necessarily

Comment: @BLUEPIXY what do you mean?

Comment: maybe sizeof(int) <= sizeof(pointer).

Comment: How is that even possible..

Comment: your comment: can't represent larger numbers then 256. is not quite correct.  The actual largest value in a byte is 255 (0xFF), however, it can store 256 values ranging from 0 through 255

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are also stored like a normal integer. 
Let the boxes be memory spaces 4 byte each.

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

After `short var = 3900;` Memory becomes

```
[3900]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

When you declare `int p = &var;`

```
[3900] //Let the address be 0x7fff9575
[0x7fff9575] //stores the address of where var is stored. It is actually an integer "2147456373" value 
[]
[]
[]
```

Hope this helps.

Edit: This is for 32bit architecture.

Comment: Is it necessary for the address to be in hex?
And are you saying that they are stored consistently? (i.e right next to each other in memory)

Comment: No it is not, however for simplicity it is written like that. Actually in the memory they are all binary.

Comment: Yeah just like i thought.